# Url encoding for query params in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-encoding

I am using Ember.js, version `1.7.0-beta.1`, in my latest project. I use the [query params](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/) feature to make a list survive a hard refresh (e.g. after a reload, the selected items in the list are still selected).

I got a controller whom manages that:

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    queryParams: [{selectedFiles: 'files'}],
    selectedFiles: Ember.A([]), //list of file ids

    ... //other props

    actions: {
    selectFile: function(file) {
        //set or remove the file id to the selectedFiles property
    }
});
```

It works awesome, but with one condition: the url is url-encoded:

Chrome & IE:

> path/354?files=%5B"6513"%2C"6455"%2C"6509"%2C"6507"%2C"6505"%2C"6504"%2C"6511"%5D

FF (*automaticly sets the brackets*):

> path/354?files="6513"%2C"6455"%2C"6509"%2C"6507"%2C"6505"%2C"6504"%2C"6511"]

Is there a way in Ember to decode the query-param-string to a more readible format? Maybe  I could use the `decodeURIComponent()` function somewhere?

The desired output:

> path/354?files=["6513","6455","6509","6507","6505","6504","6511"]

Comment: You need to use `Ember.$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`, see https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/persisting-multiple-query-params-of-the-same-name/8174/4

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a very similar problem, and made it work by overriding `serializeQueryParam` and `deserializeQueryParam` in the route.

In the controller you would have:

```
queryParams: ['files'],
files: []
```

And in the route:

```
  serializeQueryParam: function(value, urlKey, defaultValueType) {
    if (defaultValueType === 'array') {
      return value;

      // Original: return JSON.stringify(value);
    }
    return '' + value;
  },
```

and:

```
  deserializeQueryParam: function(value, urlKey, defaultValueType) {

    if (defaultValueType === 'array') {

      var arr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        arr.push(parseInt(value[i], 10));
      }      

      return arr;

      // Original: return Ember.A(JSON.parse(value));
    }

    if (defaultValueType === 'boolean') {
      return (value === 'true') ? true : false;
    } else if (defaultValueType === 'number') {
      return (Number(value)).valueOf();
    }
    return value;
  },
```

The url will then become something like:

```
?files[]=1&files[]=2&files[]=3
```

Which will then be a real array on the server side.

[Take a look at this working example on jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/leguz/25)

Comment: Awesome, these hooks are exactly what I needed. Thx!

Comment: I tried the above approach, but changed `deserializeQueryParam()` to  simply return `value` without `parseInt()`ing each of its values. Problem is, the bindings between the query parameters and the controller's `files` property weren't updating properly—it seems Ember didn't recognize when the value was being changed. So I had to call `.copy()` on `value` inside `deserializeQueryParam()` so that Ember would notice when the value was updated. Just a heads-up if someone else gets stuck on this issue.